# Android Xml command meanings?

Tags: android, xml

Hi my question is related to some xml commands used in material design designs. I don't understand what some commands mean in Toolbar and TabLayout. Is there anyone have an idea? What do the numbers of commands mean?

Toolbar

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="5"
```

TabLayout

```
app:tabGravity="0"
app:tabMode="1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You should look at the official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html)

For tabGravity

- GRAVITY_CENTER Gravity used to lay out the tabs in the center of the TabLayout.
- GRAVITY_FILL Gravity used to fill the TabLayout as much as possible. This option only takes effect when used with MODE_FIXED.
- MODE_FIXED Fixed tabs display all tabs concurrently and are best used with content that benefits from quick pivots between tabs. The maximum number of tabs is limited by the view’s width. Fixed tabs have equal width, based on the widest tab label.
- MODE_SCROLLABLE Scrollable tabs display a subset of tabs at any given moment, and can contain longer tab labels and a larger number of tabs. They are best used for browsing contexts in touch interfaces when users don’t need to directly compare the tab labels.

For tabMode ="fixed" or "scrollable"

- MODE_FIXED: Fixed tabs display all tabs concurrently and are best used with content that benefits from quick pivots between tabs.
- MODE_SCROLLABLE: Scrollable tabs display a subset of tabs at any given moment, and can contain longer tab labels and a larger number of tabs. They are best used for browsing contexts in touch interfaces when users don’t need to directly compare the tab labels. This mode is commonly used with a ViewPager.

For scrollFlags -> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41059568/11181035)